# Opening the window in new IE window when you have a function like this one

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, popup

Refining my question little bit this time. :D

I have this function, but instead of opening it in the parent window, I want it to open in a new IE window... and oh "_blank" is not working for me .

```
function saved() {
  str = parent.a.document.abc.text.value;
  SER=  top.document.open();
  SER.write(str);
  SER.execCommand();
  SER.close();
}
```

Thanks in advance 
-Miss Subanki (LOL I am asking too many questions these days)

Comment: please provide your answers fast , i am little bit in a hurray

Comment: You have better chances for fast and good answers if you make your question comprehensible by using complete sentences and such. If you don't describe your problem clearly you can't get good solutions. And demanding fast answers is also not going to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
function saved() {
  var str = parent.a.document.abc.text.value;
  var win = window.open('','','','height=300,width=400');
  var SER=  win.document.open();
  SER.write(str);
  SER.execCommand();
  SER.close();
}
```

We're opening a new window (with `win = window.open()`), and writing to it. Note that you can pass the normal parameters to it.

Comment: thanks dude a big thanx u just solved me a big problem .... 
THANX * 5555+12*89/1*59......

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need:

```
window.open('http://www.domain.com','','scrollbars=no,menubar=no,height=600,width=800,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no');
```